# Eventlet breaks select.poll

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstack, eventlet

Eventlet monkey patch seems breaking py3 select.poll() on my ENV (i try to install openstack ironic), But openstack group could not reproduce this issue, anyone knows why?

I can simply reproduce it by:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import eventlet
>>> 
>>> eventlet.monkey_patch()
>>> import select
>>> select.poll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'
>>> eventlet.version_info
(0, 25, 0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intentional, as `select.poll()` is not "green".

See also: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/608#issuecomment-612359458

Comment: I create that issue on github ：）